# Creating Features List in Wordpress Post

Tags: plugins, php, shortcode

I want to create features list in wordpress post. I know how to do in CSS but I was wondering if it can be done by using a short code or a plugin?. Like

```
[features_list]
Item 1
Item 2
[/features_list]
```

Example: 
 [image]

Comment: Why -1 vote without any explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the items in the shortcode into an array, and return a list:

```
add_shortcode( 'features_list', 'shortcode_features_list' );

function shortcode_features_list( $atts = array(), $content = '' )
{
    $content = trim( $content );

    if ( '' === $content )
        return;

    $items = explode( "\n", $content );

    $items = array_map( 'trim', $items );

    return '<ul class="features"><li>' . join( '</li><li>', $items ) . '</li></ul>';
}
```